# python import does not work in scripts

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, python-3.5

When I enter the python shell and try import for example `numpy` or `tensorflow`, there is no error, but when I run script that imports `numpy` it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\org.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf 
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "C:\Python3\lib\pickle.py", line 93, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\desktop\Nowy\workspace\python\org.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\examples\tutorials\mnist\input_data.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.datasets.mnist import read_data_sets
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import bayesflow
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops import csiszar_divergence
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\csiszar_divergence.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.bayesflow.python.ops.csiszar_divergence_impl import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\bayesflow\python\ops\csiszar_divergence_impl.py", line 43, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib import framework as contrib_framework
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\framework\__init__.py", line 88, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.framework import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\framework\python\framework\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.framework.checkpoint_utils import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\contrib\framework\python\framework\checkpoint_utils.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.ops import io_ops
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\io_ops.py", line 73, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import dtypes
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\dtypes.py", line 297, in <module>
    dtype_range = {np.bool_: (False, True),
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'bool_'
```

and tensorflow:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\org.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "C:\Python3\lib\pickle.py", line 93, in <module>
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\desktop\Nowy\workspace\python\org.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\framework_lib.py", line 76, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 37, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import errors
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import errors_impl as _impl
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import compat
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\compat.py", line 113, in <module>
    integral_types = (_numbers.Integral, _np.integer)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'integer'
```

It works earlier. I'm working on windows 10 x64, Python 3.5.2. I also tried on ubuntu 17, same case. Also when I enter python shell after executing script, importing gives me same error until i restart, in my case, powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a local file named `org.py` that shadows an optional built-in package (only used in Jython).

From your traceback:

```
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 37, in 
    import pickle
  File "C:\Python3\lib\pickle.py", line 93, in 
    from org.python.core import PyStringMap
  File "C:\Users\Jakub\desktop\Nowy\workspace\python\org.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
```

`C:\Users\Jakub\desktop\Nowy\workspace\python\org.py` is not the Jython package the `pickle` module looks for.

You only see this exception when you run your script because the directory your script is located in (`C:\Users\Jakub\desktop\Nowy\workspace\python` here) is added to `sys.path` automatically.

The attribute error is caused by the circular import; `numpy` imports `pickle` which imports your `org` script again, which imports `numpy`, but that module has not yet completed all its imports, so names are missing at this time.

Comment: Rename it to what? I've changed it to pickle2.py and now it get
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pickle
ImportError: No module named 'pickle'

Comment: @Waxy: Ah, no, indeed. It is not `pickle.py`, it is `org`. I'll update.

Comment: @Waxy: updated.

Comment: God dammit python, what the hell.

Comment: Thanks for your help .